# How to Hide Mysql Records in PHP page Every 23 Hours?

Tags: php, mysql

can I hide data from mysql every 23 hours a day and display it again after 1 hour?

for example, I want to hide the data on page at 23:00 and display it again at 00:00.

what should I add to this php code?

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "usrname";
$password = "usrpass";
$database = "dbname";

$mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
$mysqli->select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database");

$sql = "SELECT prize, result FROM qtytable ORDER BY tgl DESC LIMIT 5";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0){
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo '<div class="item">';
    echo '<div class="prizes">'. $row["prize"]. '</div>';
    echo '<div class="results">'. $row["result"]. '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    }
}
else {
    echo '0 results';
}

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

or is there a reference site for this? I hope someone recommends it to me.

I have been looking for it for a whole day, but I did not find a discussion about this. I found a way to delete records every few hours, but I didn't want to do that.

Please help me, thank you

Comment: Why not check the date/time and just skip querying?

Comment: use DateTime to check current hour and hide it. isnt it?

Comment: if the user arrives on this page at 10.59pm should the data be hidden at 11pm without him/her refreshing the page?

Comment: @RamRaider valid

Comment: @RamRaider yes that's right

Comment: If that is the case then a simple query at page load will not suffice in all respects. To accomplish the automatic hiding of portions of the page after a certain time you will need to employ some client side scripting - possibly in conjunction with serverside scripts I would think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check the current hour:

```
if(date('H') != 23) {
  // Do query and display data
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this too in another page

Answer (score 1):

You can have an if statement before executing the query and compare with the date.

** Updated to make it more effective.

```
<?php

if(date("G") > 22){
   print "0 Results";
   exit();
   // save cpu time..
}

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "usrname";
$password = "usrpass";
$database = "dbname";

$mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
$mysqli->select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database");

$sql = "SELECT prize, result FROM qtytable ORDER BY tgl DESC LIMIT 5";


$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
  if ($result->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
       echo '<div class="item">';
       echo '<div class="prizes">'. $row["prize"]. '</div>';
       echo '<div class="results">'. $row["result"]. '</div>';
       echo '</div>';
    }
  }else {
    echo '0 results';
  }


$mysqli->close();


?>
```

Comment: End for every request under the 23 hour you send unnecessary data from MySQL to PHP, you need to filter it on MySQL with a WHERE clause if the topicstarter has a datetime in his table.

Comment: Im sorry, what is that mean "G"? how do I check quickly this works or not?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php  G is the equivalent to 24 hours without leading 0.

Comment: if it was expected, you can select it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `DATETIME` column or a `CHAR|VARCHAR` column in your table which format is `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`

You can add

`WHERE HOUR(<column>) <> 23`

To your query.

Comment: I have TIMESTAMP column type, I will try this one

Comment: @DigitalFun timestamp forgetten that one, that should also work.